# Parametrize django's migration to be skipped (--fake programmatically)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, migration, django-migrations

Django 1.9 prepared me this migration (sqlmigrate output):

```
ALTER TABLE `order` DROP FOREIGN KEY `order_manager_id_refs_id_2c366637`;
ALTER TABLE `order` ADD CONSTRAINT `order_order_manager_id_20bba80d_fk_auth_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`order_manager_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`);
```

it's just remove and add the same thing.
I've just removed default values there, but

according to [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/migration-operations/#alterfield) Django never sets database defaults and always applies them in the Django ORM code, so

how to parametrize this migration to be just marked as done and do nothing on database ? Actually I need something like `--fake` parameter placed in migration code/file.

Answer (score 1):

You can run it as [fake migration](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) and it'll skip any SQL migration operations and will be written in django_migrations as completed:

```
manage.py migrate your_migration_name.py --fake
```

Comment: I know `--fake`, but I don't want remember it for every deploy it will be used.